# How to call async method inside a method which has return type?

Tags: c#, silverlight, async-await, windows-phone-8.1

This is windows phone 8.1 silverlight app.
I have a file association. For that I have a class as

```
class AssociationUriMapper : UriMapperBase
{
    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
       //here I'm getting file ID etc..
    }

    // here I want to read the file content & determine the file type because,
    // the case is, even same file extension can contain different type of data

    switch (fileType)
    {
       //here I'm calling appropriate page according to type
    }
}
```

Now the problem is MapUri is overridden method so it must have a return type. while, OpenStreamForReadAsync() is a async method. I tried Wait() method, creating new task & then calling Start(), Wait() in it but no success. Currently my code is,

```
class AssociationUriMapper : UriMapperBase
{
    string strData = "";
    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        strUri = uri.ToString();

        // File association launch
        if (strUri.Contains("/FileTypeAssociation"))
        {
            // Get the file ID (after "fileToken=").
            int nFileIDIndex = strUri.IndexOf("fileToken=") + 10;
            string strFileID = strUri.Substring(nFileIDIndex);

            string strFileName = SharedStorageAccessManager.GetSharedFileName(strFileID);
            string strIncomingFileType = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

            fnCopyToLocalFolderAndReadContents(strFileID);

            switch (fileType)
            {
                case ".gmm":
                       //determine if gmm is text
                       if (objGMM.fnGetGMMType() == GMMFILETYPE.TXT)
                       {
                           return new Uri("/PageReadText.xaml?data=" + strData, UriKind.Relative);
                       }
                       break;
             }
        }
  }

  async void fnCopyToLocalFolderAndReadContents(string strIncomingFileId)
  {
     StorageFolder objLocalFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
     objFile = await SharedStorageAccessManager.CopySharedFileAsync(objLocalFolder, TEMP.gmm, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting, strIncomingFileId);

     using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(objFile))
     {
        strData = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"with no success"*? what happens when you do that?

Comment: There's not enough context here to know what the right solution is. You could change `fnCopyToLocalFolderAndReadContents()` so that its return type is `Task` instead of `void`. Then you could call `Wait()` on it in the synchronous `MapUri()` method. But that's really a sub-optimal approach...if you have async code you should try to arrange to actually take advantage of it. But that will be difficult given that you are overriding a virtual method. Without more context, it's hard to see what a better solution might look like.

Comment: Also use `ReadToEndAsync`, `ReadToEnd` is a blocking call.

Comment: @NedStoyanov If he marks it as `async` he has to return either `void`, `Task` or `Task<T>`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov: `strData` is remaining null. Sometimes app goes into deadlock.
@PeterDuniho: tried Wait().. Didn't work.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage: yes, the way the code is now that's perfectly understandable. You're not waiting for the async method to finish, so naturally the `strData` field is invalid when you try to use it.

Comment: That happens because you cant `await` on your `async` method, and you might be checking `strData` before `fnCopyToLocalFolderAndReadContents` completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd do is change the logic. When the OS asks your app whether it supports a Uri mapping, it's expecting an immediate answer; it's not expecting the app to copy and read files. Usually, Uri mappings are very constant; an app either always supports one or it does not.

So, the first thing I would try to do is load all the mapping files at startup and *then* create the `AssociationUriMapper` with all the results. If this isn't possible, then you're almost certainly using Uri mappings for the wrong thing. They're not supposed to be dynamic, and it is quite possible that the OS will *assume* that they're not dynamic.

That said, if you want to get it working, I think the cleanest solution would be to push the asynchronous file operations to another thread and then block on that:

```
public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
{
  strUri = uri.ToString();

  // File association launch
  if (strUri.Contains("/FileTypeAssociation"))
  {
    // Get the file ID (after "fileToken=").
    int nFileIDIndex = strUri.IndexOf("fileToken=") + 10;
    string strFileID = strUri.Substring(nFileIDIndex);

    string strFileName = SharedStorageAccessManager.GetSharedFileName(strFileID);
    string strIncomingFileType = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

    var strData = Task.Run(() => CopyToLocalFolderAndReadContents(strFileID)).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    switch (fileType)
    {
      case ".gmm":
        //determine if gmm is text
        if (objGMM.fnGetGMMType() == GMMFILETYPE.TXT)
        {
          return new Uri("/PageReadText.xaml?data=" + strData, UriKind.Relative);
        }
        break;
    }
  }
}

async Task<string> CopyToLocalFolderAndReadContentsAsync(string strIncomingFileId)
{
  StorageFolder objLocalFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
  objFile = await SharedStorageAccessManager.CopySharedFileAsync(objLocalFolder, TEMP.gmm, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting, strIncomingFileId);

  using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(objFile))
  {
    return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't like it much, because it involves code that calls an async method synchronously. But the following should work:

```
class AssociationUriMapper : UriMapperBase
{
    public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
    {
        strUri = uri.ToString();

        // File association launch
        if (strUri.Contains("/FileTypeAssociation"))
        {
            // Get the file ID (after "fileToken=").
            int nFileIDIndex = strUri.IndexOf("fileToken=") + 10;
            string strFileID = strUri.Substring(nFileIDIndex);

            string strFileName = SharedStorageAccessManager.GetSharedFileName(strFileID);
            string strIncomingFileType = Path.GetExtension(strFileName);

            string strData = fnCopyToLocalFolderAndReadContents(strFileID).Result;

            switch (fileType)
            {
                case ".gmm":
                       //determine if gmm is text
                       if (objGMM.fnGetGMMType() == GMMFILETYPE.TXT)
                       {
                           return new Uri("/PageReadText.xaml?data=" + strData, UriKind.Relative);
                       }
                       break;
             }
        }
  }

  async Task<string> fnCopyToLocalFolderAndReadContents(string strIncomingFileId)
  {
     StorageFolder objLocalFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
     objFile = await SharedStorageAccessManager.CopySharedFileAsync(objLocalFolder, TEMP.gmm, NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting, strIncomingFileId).ConfigureAwait(false);

     using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(objFile))
     {
        return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
     }
  }
}
```

For me, a bigger question is why would you implement a method like `MapUri()` such that it requires calls to asynchronous methods, and involves this kind of potentially time-consuming I/O. I mean, maybe that is in fact required here, but it just seems a bit off. Unfortunately, there's not enough context in the question for me to feel like I can offer other alternatives.

Comment: The way your code is currently written, it might deadlock if called from a UI sync context.

Comment: Yes, that's true. It's one of the reasons I don't like this approach. And yes, I could throw in the calls to `ConfigureAwait(false)` to address that (maybe I should...I see you did). But IMHO it would be better to understand the bigger picture better and not have this block at all. :(

Comment: You're right, but it is a known problem that when needing to override virtual methods which dont have a proper asynchronous overload, you have to make such workarounds. Sometimes the bigger picture is the same, and you simply need to be doing it that way.

Comment: Agreed...I've fixed the code example. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no "pretty way" of overriding non-async methods.

The best you can do is make sure you add [`ConfigureAwait(false)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.configureawait%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to your async calls to make sure the `SynchronizationContext` doesn't flow and deadlock, and then access the `Result` property of the returned `Task`.

What i would do is change the method that reads the file to return a `Task<string>`:

```
async Task<string> CopyToLocalFolderAndReadContents(string strIncomingFileId)
{
    StorageFolder objLocalFolder = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current
                                                                  .LocalFolder;
    objFile = await SharedStorageAccessManager
                   .CopySharedFileAsync(objLocalFolder, TEMP.gmm, 
                                        NameCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting, 
                                        strIncomingFileId)
                   .AsTask().ConfigureAwait(false);

    using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader
          (await objFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync().ConfigureAwait(false)))
    {
        return await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}
```

And then change the call site to:

```
string data = CopyToLocalFolderAndReadContents(strFileID).Result;
```

Comment: CopySharedFileAsync statement gives error!

`'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Storage.IStorageFile>' does not contain a definition for 'ConfigureAwait' and no extension method 'ConfigureAwait' accepting a first argument of type 'Windows.Foundation.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Storage.IStorageFile>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: BTW, only copying works if I put blank `while` loop after method call that keeps checking flag `IsCopyFinished` (which I'm making `true` in async method). Reading file thing is giving problems. Causing deadlock.

Comment: @MangeshGhotage I've updated my code to use [`AsTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh779207(v=vs.110).aspx)